# How to destructure from a separate destructured property in a single line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

```
const { navigation, currentScreen, childIndex } = this.state
const screen = navigation[currentScreen]
```

How can I write this in one line of code instead of two?

Comment: What's the value of `this.state`?

Comment: It is long to post it here, but it has all destructured values. And navigation is an array of 56 object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `{ [currentScreen]: screen }`, making sure you extract `currentScreen` beforehand:

```js
const state = { navigation: { foo: 'val' }, currentScreen: 'foo' };

const { navigation, currentScreen, childIndex, navigation: { [currentScreen]: screen } } = state
console.log(screen);
```

That said, it's *really* hard to read. I'd highly recommend using your current version instead. Only code golf lines when you're [*actually* code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), otherwise it's better to optimize for readability in almost all situations.

Example with an array for `navigation` instead of an object:

```js
const state = { navigation: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], currentScreen: 1 };

const { navigation, currentScreen, childIndex, navigation: { [currentScreen]: screen } } = state
console.log(screen);
```

Comment: Thanks, but navigation is an array instead of an object.

Comment: The code should still work (but if you want to edit an example of your actual input into the question, feel free)

Comment: @witacur It does work with an array, see the snippet in the answer. It works because arrays are objects too, so using object destructuring syntax to extract properties from it is possible.